# Using variable in embedded data name in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

In Qualtrics javascript, I'm trying to retrieve earlier stored embedded data that has a number at the end of its name to display on a page. The data is stored in `result_1`, `result_2`, `result_3`, etc. Because there is a large number of results, I want to get it to work with a for-loop, but it doesn't work.

What I have now:

```
for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    resultText += "${e://Field/result_" + i + "}<br>"
}

document.getElementById("scoringCard").innerHTML = resultText;
```

But this doesn't work - the resultText returns empty.
When I do it manually:

```
for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {

if (i == 1){resultValue += "${e://Field/result_1}<br>"}
else if (i == 2){resultValue += "${e://Field/result_2}<br>"}
else if (i == 3){resultValue = "${e://Field/result_3}<br>"}
//etc., you get the picture
}

document.getElementById("scoringCard").innerHTML = resultText;
```

Then it does work. However, as there are a lot of results, this makes the code quite tedious. Any idea how I could get it to work with the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. Embedded variables get resolved server-side, so by the time your javascript executes, the values are already fixed.